# Is this undefined behaviour in C++?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I was wondering whether the access to x in the last if below here is undefined behaviour or not:

```
int f(int *x)
{
    *x = 1;
    return 1;
}

int x = 0;
if (f(&x) && x == 1) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: as far as i know, the x==1 will be executed last always. or else all my programs would break... :S

Comment: Does this even compile? Your `f` takes an int reference, and you are passing an address.

Comment: Woops, I meant to write int *x. I'll fix it immediately.

Comment: I assume you mean `*x = 1;` though.

Comment: The `&&` operator evaluates the expression on the left hand side first, and if _true_ (i.e. `true`, non `NULL` and nod `nullptr`, or any non-zero value) then it evaluates the expression on the right hand side.

Comment: this is undefined behavior : `*x++`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's **not** undefined behavior as operator `&&` is a sequence point

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I wasn't sure that `&&` would behave differently from `,` - but that must obviously be the case, since it has the short-circuit property. In my defence, it's Friday afternoon and I need more coffee.

Comment: `&&` doesn't behave differently to `,` the operator which also defines a sequence point, but does behave differently to `,` the parameter separator which doesn't. Making `,` a more confusing case.

Answer (score 7):

It is well defined.

**Reference - C++03 Standard:**

**Section 5: Expressions, Para 4:**

> except where noted [e.g. **special rules for && and ||**], the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is **Unspecified**.

While in,

> **Section 1.9.18**
>
> In the evaluation of the following expressions
>
> ```
> a && b
> a || b
> a ? b : c
> a , b
> ```
>
> using the built-in meaning of the operators in these expressions, **there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first expression** (12).

Comment: Why is it unspecified in this case?

Comment: @mattjgalloway Because the compiler gets to choose which order it evaluates its expressions in, presumably for performance purposes.

Comment: @MrLister but absolutely *not* with `&&`.

Comment: Then I don't understand what your question means. Which "it" did you mean, given that quote said "except where noted..."?

Comment: To clear the doubts,This is not unspecified behavior.Just for a few seconds I mistook and forgot completely about short circuiting though it was just for few seconds after which I corrected the same.Hmm friday evenings make me drowsy..

Answer (score 2):

It is defined. C/C++ do lazy evaluation and it is defined that first the left expression will be calculated and checked. If it is true then the right one will be.

Answer (score 2):

No, because `&&` defines an ordering in which the lhs must be computed before the rhs.

There is a defined order also on `||`, `?:` and `,`. There is not on other operands.

In the comparable:

```
int x = 0;
if (f(&x) & x == 1) {
    // something
}
```

Then it's undefined. Here both the lhs and rhs will be computed and in either order. This non-shortcutting form of logical and is less common because the short-cutting is normally seen as at least beneficial to performance and often vital to correctness.

Answer (score 2):

It is not undefined behavior. The reason depends on two facts, *both* are sufficient for giving defined behavior

- A function call and termination is a sequence point
- The '&&' operator is a sequence point

The following is defined behavior too

```
int f(int *x) {
    *x = 1;
    return 1;
}

int x = 0;
if (f(&x) & (x == 1)) {
    // something
}
```

However, you don't know whether `x == 1` evaluates to `true` or `false`, because either the first or the second operand of `&` can be evaluated first. That's not important for the behavior of this code to be defined, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not undefined, but it shouldn't compile either, as you're trying to assign a pointer to x (`&x`) to a reference.

`&&` will be evaluated from left to right (evaluation will stop, if the left side evaluates false).

Edit: With the change it should compile, but will still be defined (as it doesn't really matter if you use a pointer or reference).

Answer (score 0):

It will pass the address of the local variable x in the caller block as a parameter to f (pointer to int). f will then set the parameter (which is a temporary variable on the stack) to address 1 (this causes no problem) and return 1. Since 1 is true, the if () will move on to evaluate x == 1 which is false, because x in the main block is still 0.

The body of the if block will not be executed.

**EDIT**

With your new version of the question, the body will be executed, because after f() has returned, x in the calling block is 1.